How can I suppress local echo from cmd.exe via Python subprocess?
I would like to output some data in a separated console window on windows.
Therefore I start a new subprocess calling 'cmd' to open a new window and start writing via the stdin.write() method:
import subprocess
import time

cli_ampel_proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmd'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, text=True)
cli_ampel_proc.stdin.write('@echo off\n')
cli_ampel_proc.stdin.flush()

cli_ampel_proc.stdin.write('cls\n')  # Clear the console
cli_ampel_proc.stdin.write('echo Start\n')
cli_ampel_proc.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(3)

What I would like to have is a clean output just showing:
Start

However I get this:
echo Start
Start

How can I suppress the first line (echo Start)?

Please open a command prompt window, run cmd /? and read the output help. The Windows Command Processor cmd.exe can be started with option /Q and should be started with using additionally option /D. But what cmd.exe reads from stdin is always output to stdout as a user who types a command line must see what is already typed.

But this problem is an XY problem. If you want to output text into a separate console window from within a Python script, create a new console window and output text into this window instead of starting cmd.exe by calling the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess which creates a console window for cmd.exe. Look on the Stack Overflow search result [python] console window new.

By adding an @before your command, such that @echo start

It's been a long time since I've done cmd.exe scripting, but doesn't @echo off prevent local echo for all future commands run by the same shell? So I wouldn't expect a separate disable-local-echo sigil to be needed on later commands.

@GaTe @ left to a command line prevents the output of the command line after parsing it before execution on processing a batch file or during the execution of a sequence of commands in a command prompt window like for %I in (%SystemRoot%\*.exe) do @echo %I. But it does not prevent the output of the command line read from stdin stream. See my two comments below the question for more details. The usage of option /Q on starting cmd.exe makes it possible to enter in the command prompt window for %I in (%SystemRoot%\*.exe) do echo %I without @ left to echo.

somehow it is working in the code with the line cli_ampel_proc.stdin.write('@echo off\n'), isnt it?

@echo off\n works as it omits printing the path information. However @echo start does not work. It prints "@echo start".
